# Retrieve all items from list column in one SPD variable

Tags: designer-workflow, sharepoint-designer, workflow-variable

I am using SharePoint Designer 2010 workflow platform.

Daily our user post some press clippings in SharePoint description column, then we have to send all these descriptions in single email at the day end.

For this I am looking for how to retrieve all descriptions from description column to store in SPD variable. However, unable to find the solution.

[image: here the email body we would like to see the same using sharepoint designer workflow]

Like this

Title1
Description1

title2
description2

retrieve from SP list 
soo on

Comment: I guess I dint read your title. So from the title I am assuming You have a custom list and description as a column in it. Through out the day users add items and description column stores clippings in it. Now you want a consolidated workflow which pics clippings from all items and send an email? Right?

Comment: yes simply want to retrieve all consolidated description and title of the day from SharePoint list to Email body

Comment: Actually I am converting nintex workflow to SPD 2010 workflow, in nintex we achieve this task using foreach loop and query string,

Comment: There is nothing like that available in a SPD workflow, "downgrading" from Nintex you are going to lose most functionality. A custom timer job or an alert is your best option.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think a workflow is going to get you there, they are pretty bad at aggregating information. I believe you want a digest alert on the list that runs daily. This will pull all the posts together into one email and send that off to whomever you specify.